# A simple but painful calculation.

Tags: problem-solving

$$S=(x_3-x_1)^2+(x_4-x_2)^2+(x_5-x_3)^2+(x_1-x_4)^2+(x_2-x_5)^2$$.

$$S'=(x_3-x_1)^2+(x_4+x_2)^2+(x_5-x_2-x_3)^2+(x_1+x_2-x_4)^2+(-x_2-x_5)^2$$

Find $S$–$S'$?

I thought that, I should manipulate the above equations on my own but I got stuck, How can I reach to the answer???

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to do. Is this an equation to solve or is the right-hand side already the evaluated version of the left hand side?

Comment: What do you mean by 'the answer'? What are you trying to do with these terms? Usual quality requirements on Math.StackExchange are that you should try to provide at least a little bit of context for your question.

Comment: What are $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5$? What are you trying to find? Please be more specific.

Comment: Ok wait let me edit my post

Comment: There is a whole lot of cancellation. Determining the difference term by term (square by square) is not difficult or much work.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Evaluate the difference term by term, i.e. square by square, and use the fact that
$$a^2-b^2=(a-b)(a+b).$$
There is nothing difficult or painful about this.

In fact, it is quickly clear that in each case you get a multiple of $x_2$. The expression as a whole is quadratic, so it is a linear factor times $x_2$.

Comment: But, what about trinomials, it is hard to evaluate them

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with trinomials. Use the identity I suggested.

Comment: I mean equation having 3 terms

Comment: Have you read and tried the hint?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to perform the expansion manually, may be you could use [Symbola](https://www.symbolab.com) or a similar software.

$$S-S'=(x_3-x_1)^2+(x_4-x_2)^2+(x_5-x_3)^2+(x_1-x_4)^2+(x_2-x_5)^2 -((x_3-x_1)^2+(x_4+x_2)^2+(x_5-x_2-x_3)^2+(x_1+x_2-x_4)^2+(-x_2-x_5)^2)$$

is

$$-2x_{3}x_{2}-2x_{2}^2-2x_{4}x_{2}-2x_{1}x_{2}-2x_{2}x_{5}$$